# TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds() OPC-UA method with Simatic ProcessHistorian

Tags: opc-ua, historian

I'm trying to call `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` method (defined on View Service Set of OPC-UA standard) using OPC-UA client against Simatic ProcessHistorian (Simatic PCS 7 version 8.1).

When I browse the server with Sample Client from [UA-.NET](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET-Legacy) I can see two nodes under Objects root:

- Server
- Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}

For `Server` node the method works fine but I can't figure out a way how to get nodes down the tree starting from `Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}` (which is actually the data model).

The code looks like this (C#):

```cs
var startNodeId = new NodeId(Objects.ObjectsFolder);
var browsePaths = new BrowsePathCollection
{
    new BrowsePath
    {
        RelativePath = RelativePath.Parse(relativePath, session.TypeTree, session.NamespaceUris, session.NamespaceUris),
        StartingNode = startNodeId
    }
};

var responseHeader = session.TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds(
    null,
    browsePaths,
    out var results,
    out var diagnosticInfos);
```

The resulting StatusCode is `BadNoMatch`.

The `relativePath` parameter is `3:Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}` (the value which Sample Client displays as BrowseName for that node). I tried also without `3:` namespaceId prefix with no difference.

If I try to use NodeId of the `Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}` node as the `startNodeId` parameter, the resulting StatusCode is `BadNodeIdUnknown`.

The same code works well with other OPC-UA servers like KEPServerEX or Aspen InfoPlus21. I'm not sure if the code should be different or if ProcessHistorian just does not support it. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As @AndrewCullen pointed out there are few ways how to get the `RelativePath` instance. I examined the code in [UA-.NET](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NET-Legacy) and tried also creating `RelativePath` using its constructor, which controls every aspect of the object:

```cs
var qn = new QualifiedName("Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}", 3);
var rp = new RelativePath(null, false, true, qn);

browsePaths.AddRange(relativePaths.Select(relativePath => new BrowsePath
{
    RelativePath = rp,
    StartingNode = startNodeId
}));
```

According to [OPC UA Part 04 - Services](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-4-services/) (chapter 7.26) when the `referenceTypeId` is not specified (the first argument of the `RelativePath`'s constructor) then *all References are included and the parameter includeSubtypes is ignored*. So this construct should be the most universal (if I understand it correctly). But neither this approach was successful.

**EDIT2:**

Attaching View Node Attributes for Process Historian node:

[image: View Node Attributes for Process Historian node]

And what I actually need is to translate Browse Path for tags. Attributes of one sample tag follows in the next picture.

So I would need to resolve path like: `3:Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}/3:CMC/3:OSS1/3:OSS1_OSS1/3:ZAKLADAC/POC_VRSTEV.V` to its NodeId. There might be another catch - the slash in the name - do I need to escape it somehow?

[image: Tag attributes]

**Edit3:**

Also filed as issue at [GitHub of OPCFoundation](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final result is that Proces Historian DOES NOT SUPPORT `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds` (despite of it works for the `Server` node).

In the end I found [documentation](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109753689/process-historian-2014-sp3?dti=0&lc=en-AE) (ch 3.9.5) that the Process Historian supports only following functionality from `View Service Set`:

- `Browse`
- `BrowseNext`

which conforms to the `View Basic` ConformanceUnit of View Services, detailed in [OPC UA Part 7: Profiles](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-7-profiles/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that RelativePath.Parse follows the string format found in Part 4 - Services Annex A.2.

Try prefixing with forward slash, eg "/3:Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}"

ps. i see that if you leave off the "3:" the server will assume you meant "0:"

pps. Use the version of Parse with only arguments string, ITypeTable.  You don't need to translate Namespaces in this case.

ppps: Most browse names i see have no whitespace. I wonder why?

[image: Browse Name]

Try reading the server object?

```
var browsePaths = new [] { new BrowsePath { StartingNode= ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, RelativePath=RelativePath.Parse("/0:Server/0:ServerStatus", session.TypeTree) } };

session.TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds(null, browsePaths, out BrowsePathResultCollection results1, out DiagnosticInfoCollection infos1);

Console.WriteLine($"Expecting 'i=2256', read {results1[0].Targets[0].TargetId}");
```

Comment: Tried but prefixing the name with slash did not help. I edited my post with using of RelativePath constructor.

Comment: Reading Server properties works fine (as I mentioned in my question) - I verified that all variants: `RelativePath.Parse("/0:Server/0:ServerStatus", session.TypeTree)`, `RelativePath.Parse("0:Server/0:ServerStatus", session.TypeTree)`, `RelativePath.Parse("/0:Server/0:ServerStatus", session.TypeTree, session.NamespaceUris, session.NamespaceUris)` and `RelativePath.Parse("0:Server/0:ServerStatus", session.TypeTree, session.NamespaceUris, session.NamespaceUris)` yields `i=2256`. But neither works for node `/3:Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}` with or without leading slash

Comment: I only accidentally noticed your edit, please add comment or mention me so I get a notification. Did you manage it to work? In my case I don't even know why I'm getting `BadNodeIdUnknown` if I use the NodeId for `Process Historian {7a3ea44f-b495-414c-84f9-7498095d43bd}` (copied from View Node Attributes dialog) as `StartingNode` parameter. It looks like all the subtree is somehow not supported for `TranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds`

Comment: Could you post an image of the View Node Attributes dialog for Process Historian?

Comment: I added the picture of the dialog to my post

Comment: The picture looks ok to me.  To escape the '/', precede it with the '&' character.   “/2:Block&.Output” Follows any forward hierarchical Reference with target BrowseName = “2:Block.Output”.

Comment: You may also wish to post your question here:  https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues

Comment: Good to know (the escape character), thanks! But first I need to get it work. I tested with the tags not having the slash in the name. I'm starting to think it is limitation of ProcessHistorian (as it works for other servers)